# Approaching a Capture the Flag Question involving a text file and a sha256 hash?

Tags: encryption, text, cryptography, zip, php-ziparchive

I have to complete a capture the flag challenge. I am given a text file named notazipfile.txt containing mostly random characters, as seen at the bottom of the post. I am also given a sha256 hash as shown at the bottom of the post. I have to find a flag in the format flag{thisistheflag}. What I have worked out so far is that there is somehow a zip archive/directory due to both the name of the text file and the first few characters of the text file being PK. which usually indicates a zip file I believe.

Text file contents as a hexdump in hexadecimal:

```
0000000   P   K 003 004 024  \0  \0  \0  \b  \0 207 203   -   M 005 223
0000010 213 376  \f  \v  \0  \0   $ 036  \0  \0 023  \0  \0  \0   n   o
0000020   t   -   a   -   t   e   x   t   -   f   i   l   e   .   z   i
0000030   p   e 231 271 316 325   0 020 205 373   <   E 244 024   .   b
0000040   E     250 354   & 364   < 004   ;   H 254   B   P     304 273
0000050 363 235   3   c 233 305 377 275   7   ^ 217   g 037   ; 377 233
0000060 017 317 337 376   | 372 371 363 373 375 371 267 375 307 203 357
0000070   u 177 367 370 345 373   G   _ 257 375 311 376 345 371 267   w
0000080 257 277   =   | 271 277 374 372 350 371 267 357   _   _ 357 237
0000090 337 354 037   _   ? 376 266   ? 377 364   j 177 361 340 323 353
00000a0 353 327 266 335 375   > 316 363   < 216 373   > 312   q 336 347
00000b0   } 364 263   P   ? 357   v 037 255 035   g 277 313   q 037   |
00000c0   ( 275 234  \a 323   o   Z   T 374 275 356 233   f 275   )  \f
00000d0 334 232 266 335   n   i 301   }   2 244   _ 317   d 023 255   j
00000e0 347   Q 217 346 031 364 364   . 374   R 030   j 247   ' 326   r
00000f0 337   | 264 320  \v 004  \0   (   - 021   j   b   (   " 026 212
0000100 331 031   B   ! 265   @ 247   {   o   h 357 354   a   & 274 006
0000110 330 322 016   O 024 277  \f  \v 204 031   [ 320   x   R 025   j
0000120   k 364 226   *  \b   m       Q 250 306 246 355 340  \t   }   ,
0000130 022 320 031   S 032 373 263 224   a 276   ^ 300 303 354   [   8
0000140 332 235 207   ~   D  \n 265 242 265 305   x 235 276 273 027 232
0000150   E 202 205   0 226 210   V   @   M 246   d   z 030   V 234   l
0000160 310 220 272 026 321   4   ~ 327 346   * 225 271 332 355   : 273
0000170   &   W   @   ) 035   P 353 225 217   x   * 232   w   _   =   0
0000180 205   v   n   ~ 230 334   f 245   Z   ^ 315   3   , 177 364 004
0000190 321 327 263 243 365 235   ^ 206 201 265 336   <   Q 032   0 374
00001a0 035 252 362 357 026   [ 206 326 316   +   V   U 343 027 375 210
00001b0  \0 211 321   B   9   < 251   4 332 324   $ 241   B 315 234 016
00001c0   F 303 244 264 250 230   T 223 031 223 273 350   e   :  \f   K
00001d0 271 241 305 356  \r   )  \b   2 344   # 213   > 202 321 304  \f
00001e0   Q   n   6 343 232 264 262   a 260   e   T 233   z   k   T 354
00001f0 034 250   J   s 001   = 033 025 021   [ 003   P 024 263   0 004
0000200 335 001  \r   }   u 323   "   Q 206 262   d   T 207 276 262 235
0000210  \n 024 237   g   R   & 226 017 250 266 244 243   4 364   n 246
0000220 264   ) 337   ` 313 224 252   7 034   F 020 036   / 352 250 035
0000230 337   a   ? 223   j   #   8   O 366 357 260   _ 250 301 273 364
0000240 356 255   % 353 020 300   5   d   J 247 351 302  \b 365 221   0
0000250 020   V 210 262 341 017   U   f 206 342 302 337 005   J 301 212
0000260 252   e 026 342   9 003 305   O   Q 032   b 317 301   X     247
0000270   .   f 253 325   #  \b 261 344   @   / 317 020   8 244 366 253
0000280 321 247   !   C 247   ] 372 211   L 243 341   1 263   M 003   :
0000290 257 263   u 372 204   { 331 260 212 376   h 365   J   ? 265 022
00002a0   8 226 273 325 233 217 004 345   c 300   p 211 214   . 320   l
00002b0   u 211 254 363 222 313   Q   z 207   R 204  \t 235 266   b 351
00002c0   A   V   B   e 004   ) 251   v   s   } 354   H 247 311 026   f
00002d0   Z 230 242   ] 177 206 370   { 353   4 360 017 364 225   ! 265
00002e0 016 037 022 231 006   z 306 257 355   4   6 361 350 245 001 313
00002f0   8 205   x 026   @ 367 262   ? 273 241 255 243 264   ^ 370 301
0000300   f   '   u 226   *   S 275   * 234 032 320   3 314 327 273 005
0000310 252 326 004   1   @   R 004 312 003 264   Z 335 301   ^   Z   |
0000320 006 235 341 250 031   8 316 214 247 336 251   % 275 262 222 036
0000330   z   + 016 357 347   U 366 266 357 320 330   T 020   g 273 232
0000340   m 250  \a 235   V   X 362   w   G   ^ 332   F   O  \b 025   t
0000350 247 020   G   M 326 243   p 021 332   w 310   + 265   _   u 357
0000360 327   u   ! 024      \f 032   L 333 362 207 216   a 237 347 324
0000370 225  \a 231 037   * 302   h 370   C 256   ` 326   ]   d  \n 363
0000380 331 376   L   r 225 261  \r 235 353   ;   V   g 224 312   L 022
0000390   m   =   E   E   1 377   R 024 265   " 234 253 202   H   u 177
00003a0   V  \0 225   k 364   t   L 276   #   } 244   5   l   v 244 220
00003b0 205 304 030 332 254 312 004 300 351 323   1 367 275 302   5 324
00003c0 236 302   D   Y 265 265 242 030 025  \n   Q 031   A   *   r   T
00003d0  \r   _   ( 261 333 034   R   x   G 214   | 332   !   = 235 275
00003e0 326   g 030 302 216 347 027 224   v 310 200 235  \0 274   >   S
00003f0   l  \b 244   m 361   L 303   2  \a 226   v   Q 372 001 212 345
0000400 327 263 006 245  \r 005 201 333 236 365  \v   8   y   @ 037 216
0000410 357 310   / 275 375 021 371   c 207 351   i   9   V 332   3 246
0000420   V 210 305   < 257   V 371 273 250   = 273   .   (   = 025 374
0000430   " 224 271     266   ! 005 203   f   } 376 036 232   . 345 241
0000440   b   4 365 254 301 367 271   W 200   ! 263   a  \b 352   o   "
0000450 214 350   =   4 224 202   u   f  \n   ;   5 335   I 253 245   `
0000460   w   R 232 224   g   ^ 235 277   g   W 203   N 370   G 024 350
0000470 351 222   U   ( 375 017 231   e 355   T 227 342 351 220 364 214
0000480   V 303 033   d 374   R 364 305   w 277 240 024   T 314 240   "
0000490 227 206 266 222   :   e 211 245 377 221 242 251   ;   n   f   )
00004a0 016   ^ 201 212   =   5 020 237 325 326  \r  \n   l 251   U 277
00004b0 227 316   h 221   * 027 346 262 365   m 304 202 351   T   C 302
00004c0   r   : 311 024 325 213   y 241 241 371 353 334   i 240 251 310
00004d0 364   S 033   k   = 222 331 006 335 263   ;   '   ) 025 313 362
00004e0 237 211 312   Z   !   Y 017   t 177 235 265   b   O   > 346 255
00004f0   3   C   2  \v   $ 323 266   P   O 016 305   H 362 257 231   x
0000500 351   u   A 037   x 372 261   k   ) 237   ` 305 262 366 324   z
0000510   I 237 201 210 312 002 345   }   I   . 016 003 271 345 234 202
0000520 300   (   U 314   S   x 002 332 344   g   g   s 370 017   o 321
0000530 303 322 002 321   ; 335   [ 017 003   g   ^ 300 006 262   i   E
0000540  \a 262 034 030   G 250 002 025 245 247   y 227 300   e 313   |
0000550 203 006 020 273   [   r 370 215   q 237 270 211 277   S 244   `
0000560   F 274   E 035 212   I   l   j 366 233 214 024   D   Q  \0 037
0000570  \f  \a   w 266 240 214   {   a   R   M 365 220   G 233 346   !
0000580   B   D   & 210 372 342 243   !   S   $ 345 264 245   S 232   p
0000590   F 212   R 336   r   a 266 264   o 375   e   n   F   T 336   O
00005a0   - 033 207  \0   n 005   }   [ 226 324   ~ 364 213   I   `   .
00005b0 177 327   9 246 247 335   W 346 024 237   P   b       N   z   5
00005c0   O   F   * 322   U 271   @ 220 241   <   C 242   r 245 242 301
00005d0 262   d 245 275 257   >   r   ~   U 224 337 272   p 362 322 240
00005e0 001   E 350 274   Z 370   J   u 002   t   !   X 364   D 261 323
00005f0 037 222 315  \0 264 274 213   -       2   4   1   l  \v 262 223
0000600   g   3 301 303 360 022 201 314   G   ' 034 246 002   * 223 361
0000610 271   h   2   G 222 325 037 375 356   %   k   J 213 276 361   A
0000620 210  \n 275  \n   @ 247   [ 367   , 212 361   V   c 177 346 003
0000630 334 032   9 275 254   i 370 220 250   " 263   w   E 251   K 244
0000640 205   J 355 357 324   C 234 372 025   Q 261 004 005   \     226
0000650   8 301 213   8   [ 253 235 261 217   ;   T 350   b   c 341 364
0000660   " 365   e 234 246   % 371   ? 323   q 321   4 300 245   A   5
0000670 320   t 206 266   @ 265 024   ^   )   z 016   s 260 366   - 317
0000680 314 264 314   0 345   G 321 243   J 236   > 362   ) 244 370 250
0000690 247 004   k   w 034 326   ? 017 376 367  \b 314 233 033 347
00006a0 335   ^     377 272   t 244 226   Q 016   %   W 031 223 375   }
00006b0 036 275   } 326 270 257 300 264 260 021 245 312 026 201   o 304
00006c0 361   l 311 207 230 217  \n   t 324 227 320 312   3   ] 370 224
00006d0 276 366   b   \   B 206 025   t 373   < 023 242   ? 367   8   Q
00006e0 370   v 242   > 251 315 247 207 260   - 354   ] 247 006 321 375
00006f0  \f 324 212 235 002 300 360 263   b 023   k   b 213   J 372 273
0000700   F   t 357   L 231 016 303 367   f   G 336 330 345 357   R   /
0000710 350 312   {   :   S   c 370  \f 310 360 020 264 254   E 346 020
0000720 207   o   f 032   " 305   2   @   S   { 262 202 344 337   G 022
0000730 210   } 366   l 357 002 023 250 005   i 355   ] 034 177 252 244
0000740 354 270 353 262 022 177 260 357 355 326   M   0   . 351   J   y
0000750   | 257 035   h  \t  \r 213   2   U   J   + 234 374 236   =   #
0000760 274 304 355 304   v 263   J 202 346 335 321 277 343   F 205 344
0000770 224 347 265   V 332   " 004  \f   P 342 325   3 237 004 272 364
0000780   S 035 023 330 335 033  \f   ;   m   y 213   *   w 336 276 314
0000790 211   \ 025 006 235 225 232   |   K 224 212   ,  \t   ; 322  \0
00007a0 252 327 354   q   Z  \n   b 242 261  \t   r 334 002 302   + 347
00007b0   i 277 211 330   F 340 363 234   &   _   < 305 001 272 333 035
00007c0 254 207   b 274   v 374 006 373 223 361 250 314   w  \n 021 356
00007d0 272 302 237 275 214   _ 031 254 224 206 264   Q 345   X   3 016
00007e0 322 276   , 230 375   s   ! 346 340   H 004 016   j   p   m 213
00007f0 221 346 030 212   3   k 327   @ 231 213 362   g 352 313 267 350
0000800 241 361   5   K       N   C 027 240 254   g  \f 263 264   3 322
0000810 253 236 346 003 312 237 227   0 177   " 325   o 203 335 261 245
0000820   m   O  \r   % 375 240   5 203   L 034   8 320 223   i 035   Q
0000830   `   ` 217 226 331 257   D 204 311 302  \n 301 326 027 212 342
0000840 203 312 224   &   2   e   T 033 220   l   f 035   =   c 371 324
0000850 231 331 377   3 226   $ 236   g 370  \f 316 305 301   / 272 244
0000860   }   i 354 242 242   [ 357   L 346 236 230 270 343   " 221 233
0000870 234 201 031 335 177   d 177   . 017 366 331 003 257 365 033 031
0000880 222 034   = 313   + 003   5   I   R  \v   a 217 253 371 230 265
0000890   , 301   b   U 360 223 336   e 247 266   W   v 341 241 233 304
00008a0 360 357 244 372 210 222 212   *   N   "   S 217 177 026   E   M
00008b0 371  \0 273 303 276   \ 035 270   p   0   J 263 017 331  \a 003
00008c0   n   ^ 227   $ 323   ?   9   ^ 366 037 367 315 242   $ 215 306
00008d0 223 211   & 310 271 236 255   , 324 277  \n   =   [   :   f 213
00008e0   c 243 367   T   u 274 247   T   d   Q   N 032   . 241 034 257
00008f0 025 353 255 203 257 035 261 332 327   v   x 331 342 314   < 212
0000900   {   ;   O 025 207 265 342   3   H 334 304   *   5   ; 355   4
0000910 352   @ 215   t 036 300   T 315   ~ 251 342 311   e 032   ~ 324
0000920 265   & 246   + 223 362   M 313   9 247   I 235 343 272 257 256
0000930 222 206 264 361 323 246   =   e 311   J 002   f 373 217   Q   ]
0000940 202   g 222 017 217 231 207 211   0 376 263 256 230   5   F 215
0000950 347 220   " 022 322 336 326   X 367 001   G   &   6   . 035  \t
0000960 272 356 373   3 235   L 337 322   +   "  \t   / 003   ) 276 251
0000970 227   [   w 347   7 256  \r 371   n 207 240 032   K 203 373 351
0000980 260   [ 320 230 220 236   S   4   7 206 347   ~ 276 353 325 035
0000990 345 215   ` 244 242   K 266   $ 344   z   R   g 320   %   -   z
00009a0   u 202 213  \v 342   b 227   6 025   2 240   2 213 316   K 363
00009b0 212 343 027 267 362 333 341 367   % 211 335 376 310   w   q 322
00009c0 370 367   Z 315 233 366   <   )   e   "   r 254 036 246 032 016
00009d0   2   .   # 330   p 202 016 314   ? 256 250   Y 261   0 342 346
00009e0 021 231 314 267 353   n 247 266   x 247 033   (   r   W 307 036
00009f0 251   b 313 220 030 027 327 245 261 231   z 022   J 004 214 267
0000a00   u   C 242   C 347   ^ 216 377 272   " 031 022   P  \f 242 200
0000a10   6 255   b   !   3 332 214 326 343 264 345   ~ 353   <   }   #
0000a20   v 377   s 211   |   _   d 214 243 374 237   C 343   E 233 257
0000a30 177   :   $   b   g   5 017 242   u   f 245   3   1 227 210 375
0000a40 242 333 316 256   - 263 177   ! 307 215 263 213 225 274 252 373
0000a50 231 222 035   n 232   V 377   W 276 336   |   V 370 333   M 327
0000a60 213 037 277 031 232 363   ]  \v 227 232 323 377   }   U   `   $
0000a70 330 237 215 277 242   ~   < 326   { 374   U   |   )   Z 211   l
0000a80   -   [   g 251 271   ~ 236   T 262 342 277 226   | 256   U 177
0000a90   m 226   j 370 357 324 027   g 250 177 336   Z  \f 027   = 377
0000aa0   l 257 334 356 177 264 374 263 317   ( 351 373   +   j 215   @
0000ab0 232 032 261 361 374 313 372   x 031 221   7 343     330 375  \v
0000ac0 177 373   +   +   / 207  \n 335 377   e 017   + 354 244 261   .
0000ad0   9   Q 246   , 234 367 243 222 003   k   l 316 360   g 301 216
0000ae0 026 207 201 245 206   e 250   %   d 032 355   x 350 306 373   g
0000af0   |   2 342 030   ] 357 237 376 212 240   ^   1  \t 032 332   _
0000b00 022 377   C   , 340 375 365   n 355 217   C   < 317 261 347   "
0000b10   q 355   9   A 377 322 361 221 245  \t 362   _ 335   .  \t 313
0000b20 336 326 232 370 313 313 344   6   R 303 037   > 345 252 231 217
0000b30   y 377 036 266 377   ~   q 270   V 315 315 267 337   P   K 001
0000b40 002   ?  \0 024  \0  \0  \0  \b  \0 207 203   -   M 005 223 213
0000b50 376  \f  \v  \0  \0   $ 036  \0  \0 023  \0   $  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000b60  \0  \0  \0      \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   n   o   t   -   a
0000b70   -   t   e   x   t   -   f   i   l   e   .   z   i   p  \n  \0
0000b80      \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 001  \0 030  \0   w   1   a   K 240   K
0000b90 324 001   {   K 317 026 237   K 324 001   {   K 317 026 237   K
0000ba0 324 001   P   K 005 006  \0  \0  \0  \0 001  \0 001  \0   e  \0
0000bb0  \0  \0   =  \v  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000bb8
```

Sha256 hash that is given: e62391166a9c9fe0eefbc999958f87f2b454f36cadeb2c026b9000bdc9abddf6

I have tried to view the metadata of the text file which did not reveal any useful information. I have also tried to change the extension of the text file to .zip, which results in an invalid file error on windows. I have also tried to extract a zip file from within the text file using the ZipFile library within Python, which results in errors or unmeaningful results.

Comment: There is really not enough information here to give concrete aid. However, from reading this [article](https://musyokaian.medium.com/capture-the-flag-93ddd8eb2e18) it seems you should probably assume that the file is in fact an encrypted zip-archive, and that the hash is something you can use with john the ripper or hashcat or similar to brute force it. Also, you need to get the file in a binary form to work with it - the "text" form in your post will not be usable. If you got the file as a .txt file, you still need to treat it as a binary file, and then rename it - presumably to .zip .

Comment: The file isn't text at all. You need to post an ascii-hex dump of the file or a link to the original file.

Comment: @DavePatel don't see any hexdump. Probably too long for a comment. Try editing you original question and add it there.

Comment: @Xecrets so you are suggesting that I have to convert the text representation of the file to something such as ASCII or hexadecimal? And then attempt to use hashcat or john the ripper to brute force it?

Comment: @pmqs I have posted the updated hex dump version of the file in the original question now.

Comment: What you provided is not a hex dump. It is a combination of ascii-octal, printable ascii & back slashed escapes. Assume you've used `od -c` to create the file? Managed to decode it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you provided is a perfectly valid zip file that contains a single file, called `not-a-text-file.zip`.

I saved it as the file `data.zip`

The standard Linux `unzip` thinks the file is fine

```
$ unzip -t data.zip 
Archive:  data.zip
    testing: not-a-text-file.zip      OK
No errors detected in compressed data of data.zip.
```

It also extracts fine

```
$ unzip  ../data.zip 
Archive:  ../data.zip
  inflating: not-a-text-file.zip
```

Below are the contents of `not-a-text-file.zip`. All characters are 7-bit printable ascii charactes.

````
flag{Look at y0u, h4ck3r. A pathet1c cr3ature of me4t and b0ne.}

@;@#+++##@@#'#+@+@#;+'@#'+@:@#::#+;@'#@##@####;'+##++@#@#+###+###.@@@#@,@@@@++@@@###
@@@@@+####@+@,@#@+@###.@#@@###+:+#,#:@@+###@@;;'#@#''@##:++@###,'@@'@@,@#@@@###@#@+#
@#@@++###@##@@@@#+@+'#+,@@:@#@#:'@'#@@#+@@'+@;:+#@#'+@@@++#++@':#@@:@#@;@#+@;#@##+#@
####@+++#@@##@::##+',+@@'@@@#@#;+@'@@+##:#'@@#:+#+#:#@@++@@'@@:'#++#@##:@##@@#@###@#
@@@###+#+@@@#+#@@#+#'+@+#@'#@@+'+##:#;+#'@;'@+''###;#@;##+++#+:'#@#@;@@,@@###@@##@#'
@+@#@@+#'@#@#@###+;#++#####,@@,+#+@.+;@##@,'@++++;#;#+##@@#@@',+@'#,@@@.;###@@#+@#@+
#+@#@@@@##:+@#@#+@@@+:###@@@@,@##,##@'.`#:; ###+@@+;#@+###@@@+:+@+'@#@@'@@#@@@#@#@@@
#@@#@@#@#@+#+.##+@@+,:+@#@'+@#@;####+#:#+#'+##@+#+':+#:#@++#@''#:#@#@@+'@#@#@##@@###
####'@@@@##@#+@#@++#@;+@@@:#@'@+@@:@+#@@##;#+@@++++:'#+######;+'#@#@@@@@#@#@##@#@@+#
#@#+#,@@#@#@++'@##@@@+;+@@@#;'+#::@@#++##@'@;@#+#++:+:@#+:#@+,#@@@@@@''#@####@@#@;+#
@##@#';#@@##:####@###+,+@@#+@@#@++@,#+##+#`#'@##''+:++@@@+#`':;@@+@@@:+##@+##@@:@+##
#@#@@@:###@@;@++@+##@+':###,;''@';#@@#+++@.+;++#';;:'#'++#;+',@@@+@@#@@+#+#@#@##.###
#####@@@#+@@'##'##',@@#+'#@+#@@#:::#,+;#+@'+#+###+;:'####@.;,#@#@+@@#++#+##@@@##+##@
#@##+####+@@#++#'####@##,''@@:+#:,##@@+#+@@''#+;#'`;+@#'+;.:+@@@@+##@#@+#@@@@##+#@@@
@#@@@##++##@#+':####++'#.+:;+##@:+#.@;###'#'#':+#;,;+##':'+#@@@@@@#@+@##@@@+@##@@@@@
@#@@#@#@#+'##@@#+++###@#+#'+,+@@;+@#+.@+#'''';;;#'#;+'+;'+@#@#@@;@@#;@#@@@@###@##@++
@@###@@@@@#@+#@#@@##+@#+##@++'@#;;'#;`.##;:;#;;+.#+;+#++@#@#,@@@#@#@@@@@+@@###`@@#+#
#@@@@@##@#@#@.@#####+##+#+@@''+';;' ' `@+;';:::;':::#@'#;@#@@@@#@@@+#@@'##+####,##@#
#+@@@@@'@@@@+@.@####@'#+#++@#';;;;; ' `;;;:::,,;;;;;'+',##@+@@#@#@:#@#@@+@#@#+@+#+#@
##@+#@@:@@@@##@,#@#;##++##'##:+++.' :  ::;:::::+'+:.:#++#+;@@#@@@'+#@@####+##@++##@@
#@@####+@@@#@+@@:#+:+####;#'+:'#'; ' ; ;;'',;., ;...+';#+#;@@#@#+#####+#@##+++###@@#
+##@@###@@@@##+#@;#+@++'@#:'+'+'''+ ; , ::::., ;` `;'::##@:@#@@@@##@@##@@@##+#@@@###
#++#@@###@@@#####@;#+#'++##'''+''++' `;'.,, ;+'  `';':,''@;+#@#@###@#@@@###+#@@@#@#@
+@@#+@++##@##'##@@@+#,+#'@'++'++';#;, ,;.., :+  `',;;,::'@+,###@+#@@@@@@####@@####@#
,#@@@+@'#@@@######@@###+;#@;'';'':#:  :+;,,`;;  ;:'':;:##;;'@+####@@@+@#'+@@@@#@@@@:
@#@@@@#+@@@@@#+#@@+###@'',+@:+;;:#.`: ,;:...,,`:`;.;;'#+;+;@@@+##@##@@+'#;@@@##@@###
##@@@@#@@#@@@@###@@@##@@':`@+','';::,.:,:,:.::,`..'':+'#'+@#+'#@@@@@@'###@@@@@@#@###
@@@@@@#@@@@@#@@@##'+@++#@'::'''`:;,,+ ,:,.,`:: ; '::':'#;@+@,#@@@###++#@@@@@###'@#@@
#@;@@@#@#@@#@@+@@@@#+#+++@+';';:.;.;.`.::.:..,.`:,;;.'+''#;#@@@@@@#+##@@@@@@+;#@@##@
###@@@+@@#@@#@#@##@@####+;#'+,;;,.;;, .:,..:., ,,':`:;:'++#@@@@#@+'#@@@@@@###@#@#@@@
@##;+##@@@@@@@@'@##@+####+;++':;;,`,:;.:,....:',,..:'.''@##@#@+++'#@@@@@@####@@@####
#@@+@#@####@@@@##@@@#@@@@+++#''`:: ,.::.,,..`;..+ ::.:+'+'@#@#@@#@@@@@#####@@@@##+''
@@@###@######@@@@@@@@@###++:+';#`;.:,,,:;;:,,,..'.+,,;+;;@#+@###'@@@@##+##@@@@#+':,,
@#@@+@'@@@@####@@@@#@+######+#''+..;..,,,..,,, ,;.;,;+',+'+@@+#@@@@@'####@@#+';,'+.#
@#+':;'#@###@@##+######@@#+'++'''',::.,,,,,::, ,:;'';+:+;+#+@@#+#@+@@#@@+++;,''+@@+@
;','';:;+:@###@@#@@##+@+###+'#''#;;;:.::,,,:,, ,+,;+;;+++#+#@'+#@#####@+;,;'+#@#@'#@
;++#@#''::+#@@@@@@@@+@+#@++##'+'';':';:,,..,::,;;;;+;+:@+'+#'+##@@##@##;++#@@@###@@@
@:@@@#@#+';,:'#@@@@@@#++#+#''#;':#;'::,:,..,,,':;+';;'++:';++##@@@+#@@::#@@@@@@#;'''
@#'@@@@@#+++#:+;#@@@#@#++##+''';;'@;'',:: ,.,,;+#;.+;#+:''###@@@@@@@@#:;@#@#@@@,,,;'
#@##@@@@@#;+@@@#,@#@@+#+++++#+'+'.#+:+':,`,, :;:''+#++'+#@@@@@@@@#+''.;###@##@+,##@;
;@#,@@@@#@#;##@#+#,+##@+++#+@#;++:;:.';',,::::'+''##+#+#@@@@@#+'';:,,'+@@#@###,##':+
@#@#@@@@@#@#+;@#@##+;;##@##++#'';+':'+#':,::,''+:######@@@@@#;::;:;:;''+#####:#++;+:
@;@#';'''''###;.'++;''''@@@@@@@@@@#;;'+';,:;`++#'#@@@@@@@@@@+''''':;'+'##+'+#++##';@
##.#+;;';;'+++++#';';++#+'+++#+###@+'##+',;'.'#@'@#@++#;''+;+++#@'@@@;#@@#@####+++++
+#+#+######@##++@@@##'+##@''.;`:+@@+'+#+:;:'.'#@##@':`':;@#+''#+##@;@@@@##@;##@@@@@@
#@##@#@#+#@#@@@#;@@#+;;'#'#+;;,:'+#@+#'',:;;;'+@#++';''+@@'+#'+##@,#@@@@@@'@@@@+@@#@
@@'@@+@####+++#@#+'#'':.'##'+#;.@@@@#+'',:''++#+@@####@@@#++'+''@.#@@@@@#'#@@#.#####
@###@#++#@@@@#@###@#+'::,''@:;'+@.+@@@;'`,'@+'+@+ '@@###',';'+'#@+@++'###@+'+ ##+#@@
@##@'#####';++'++@#@#+;:+'',;;#+'#`+@@,',,'#@'++`'':'+#:+++#:'+@@@###@@'++##,@@@@@@@
@@@@#@#;'###@####@#@+#;':''+;#+;;.;.'+,+::'#@+'''#;,:;;';',;''##@@#''+@#@#;###@@@#@@
@@@@#@@@##@;+######@#+':+;,,'',`` ;#@+'+::'@@@#++;;,:.  `,,:''#@@#++++++##@@@@@@#@@@
@####@@#@@@#@#@##@+@@@#+:;;,:;;. ,''++'#;:'#@@#';;:,` ```.,,+@@@@++#@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@##'@##@@@@##@@@@@#+@@'''::..,``.,;'+@++::'#@@#';:: `;.`.:;+'##,,,::::;;+@@@@#@@@@@@
:#+####+'@@'+#+##++##@+;''`,,,,, ,:'+++#;:'@@@+;':'::,,,:'+'+##+#@@@@###@@#+@@@@@@##
+###'##+#####+###@#++@#';;;:::..:+:++###':;#@@+''::;.; :;+';##@@@#@@#####@#####@#@@@
@#@@@##@@@@@@@##@@#@@@@##:;',,::;#;++@@#+;+@@@@;'+'+:,:;':+@@@@@@@#@##@@@###;##+@@@@
+@##@@@@@@@@##@@@#@@@@@#++;:;:;;:'''+@##+:;@#@@;'';';;:;;'@@@@@@@##@@@##@@#@#@@@@@@#
#@###@+@@@#@@@@@@@##@@##+++:';.;:';;'@#@',;@@@#'+:'';;':'@#@##@@@@@##@#@##@##@'#@###
@@#@@@@#@@##@@@#''#@@@@##++'':;:;;:#;@@#+;'@@@@#:':';';;#+@@####@#@##@@@@@####@#@@@@
,@.#@##@@@##@#'#@@@@@@@#@#++::.::.;;;#,##'+@@#@#,:::;;:#+#@#@@+@@@@###@@@#@@#@@#####
#@##@@@@#@###@#@@@#@#+#@@#@#+;+;`',#:#'@':;#++@@.':;;#'##@@@@@@#+@#@#+###@@@#@####@#
#@@@#@@+@###@##@#####@@@@@@#++#`;;+':+;#;,,+:'#+,'+;+'+##@@@@@@##+@#@##@###@###+@'@#
@#@@#@#+##@@@@@#@@@@@@@@#@##++:;'++:;@##'::++###`;++#;'#+@####@@##'##@@@########@###
@'##++@#@@@@@##@@@@@@@@@@@@@##',;;::@'@@':,+@@#;':'+++####:@#+@@+##++#####@###@@###+
#@######@@@@@@#@@##@@#@@@#+#@##''';+:':@@@#@@@::'++##@###@@#@@'@#+@##############@#+
###@#++:++''''+####++''+++#@@##''':';''#@@@@@#+:;''##@#@@@@#@+#@##+#++++'''';;;;';':
###++:::::::::;;;';;::;;;;;@@++#''';:,+;@@@+,;:,;++@@@@##@@@#'+#@##++'+++#++'''''+++
#@#','++#######@@@@##++####@@+#@#++#++';;'+;;'##@@@#@+'##@@@@@@+'+#@@###+'##'@@#@@+@
@@+:+@###@##@@@@@@@@#@@@@@@@#++#++@@#@@@@#@@@@@@@@#@';#;;##@@@@@@@#'#@@@@#@####+####
#+,#####@#@@@#@@@@#@#@@#++++;:;##+'#+##@@@@@@@#@#@@#;+#++#:++#@@@@###+@@@#@###@@@###
#+###@@#@@@@##@@@@#@+'+;,;++++###':@#,#'+;@;#'+@@@'##@+@@###:;+#@@#@@##+'##@@###@@@#
##@#@@@@@@##@+#@@#':;+####@@@###@@#@@@., ,,, ;;@#@##@'#@@@@@+;;:++#+@@@@+#+###@@@@@#
@@@#@@@@@@#+#':;''++#@@@@@@@@@#@#'++@@@;. , ,:@;##@@'####@@@#@'++,'+#@@@#@##'#@@###@
@@##@@@@@#+++'###@@@@@@#@@@@@#@@@+@;@@@@'@@##@@#+@@#@@;#@#@@@@##@##''++#@#'':''####@
@@#@@@@@#+;+##@@@@@@@##@@@@@#@@#'##;++####'###+++@;+@#@@'+@@@##@#@@@@#:'';,;;+':;+++
@+@@@@#++'#@@#@@#@@@@##@@#@##@@@'###+++###@+@#+##@+'#@@@@@++@@@#@##@@#++:'+#@@#++#':
@'@@@##'+;+@#@###@@@@#@@@@##@@@'@:#@+@#;####';@@@@#;+#@@##@@+#@#@@#@#@@@#@@@@##@@@#+
#+++''+:####@@#@@@@##@@@@@+@#@#+##+@+@@#.+'+,@@@@@@',##@#@##@#+@@#@#@@#@#@@@@##@@@+#
;;';;+#@##@#@@@@#@@#@@@@##@#@@++;@'@@@@@@+++@@@@@###+++@#@@@@@@+@@#@###+@@@@@@@#@##@
+:++#@###@##@@@@@@@@@@@@#+#@@@#'+@+@@@@@@@#@+@@@@#@@#;##@##@@@@@#@####@@@@##@@@@###@
#+##@@@@####@@@@@@@@#@##@@@#@#+'#@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@##+;#@#+#@@#@###@@@@@@@@@@#@@@@@@
@##@@@#@##@@@##@@@#@@@##@#@#@#:+@#@@@@@@@@@@@@#@@@@#@#+'#@#@@##@@#@@@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
#####+@#@@@@@#####@@@#@@@###@+####@@@#@@@#@@@@####@#@##:+@@@@@@@@#@@@@#@@@@@@@@@@@@#
##@@#@####+###++####+@@@@@#@#;+#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#+#@@@@@';#@@@#@#@#@@#@@#+#@@#@@@@#@@
##@#####@@@@@@@@@@@@##@#@#@@+#@@@@#@@#@@@@@@@@@@##@+@@@#;+##@@@##@#@####@@##@@#@@#@#
#@#@@#@@####@@#@@##@@#@@#@@#@@#@##@##@@#@@@@@@@@@##@@#@@':+##@@@##@@@@@#@#@@@@#'@@@@
#@#@#@@#@#@#@+;@#@@@@@@@#@#'+##@###@@#@#@##@@@@@@####@@##+'##@@##@#@@@##@@#@@##@@@@@
@#@@@@@@@@#@#@@#@@@@#@@+#####@@@+@@#@@###'@##@@@@#@##@@#@#'+#@@@#@#@@@@@##@@@@@@#@@@
@#@@@###@@@#@@@#@@########:@@@+#@@@@#@@@@@@@@@@@#@@#@@@@@@#:+@@#@@@#@@#@#@#@#@@@'@@@
#@+@@######@##@@@@@###@##'+###@#@@@@#@@@##@@@@@@@###@@@@@@#+##@@@@##@@@@@##@#@@@@@@@
````